# How to get a list of current variables from Jinja 2 template?

Tags: templates, jinja2

If I return a Jinja2 template like so:
`return render_response('home.htm', **context)`

How do then get a list of the variables in context from within the template?

Comment: How about reading the template source?  What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Technically, because context is not passed as a named dictionary, a little work is required to generate a list of the context variables from inside a template.  It is possible though.

1. Define a [Jinja context function](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.contextfunction) to return the jinja2.Context object, which is essentially a dictionary of the global variables/functions
2. Make that function available in the global namespace; i.e. a jinja2.Environment or jinja2.Template globals dictionary
3. Optionally, filter objects from the context; for instance, use `callable()` to skip Jinja's default global helper functions (range, joiner, etc.).  This may be done in the context function or the template; wherever it makes the most sense.

Example:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> 
>>> @jinja2.contextfunction
... def get_context(c):
...         return c
... 
>>> tmpl = """ 
... {% for key, value in context().items() %}
...     {% if not callable(value) %}
...         {{ key }}:{{ value }}
...     {% endif %}
... {% endfor %}
... """
>>> 
>>> template = jinja2.Template(tmpl)
>>> template.globals['context'] = get_context
>>> template.globals['callable'] = callable
>>>
>>> context = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> 
>>> print(template.render(**context))
        a:1
        c:3
        b:2
```

[Alternately, call `render_response` with `('home.htm', context=context)` to make the other solution work.]

Comment: Note that because of the `callable` check, your solution would disregard functions that have explicitly been passed as part of the context. Probably doesn't happen often, but could make a difference.

Comment: True.  This simple solution can definitely be improved.  For instance, if ``template`` is a global, ``get_context()`` can return a new dictionary based on ``context`` but without keys that also exist in ``template.globals``.

Comment: Added a feature request to enable this by default https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/174

Comment: @techtonik Any news? I struggle with exactly this

Comment: @Strajk, I asked Armin, but not sure he has the time to look on that. For me the pull request with a screenshot would be more convincing than some code piece and some idea floating around.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to get [@crewbum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463669/503463) working from a Flask app:

```
import jinja2

@jinja2.contextfunction
def get_context(c):
    return c

app.jinja_env.globals['context'] = get_context
app.jinja_env.globals['callable'] = callable
```

Comment: Where do you put this?

Comment: In the app initialization (or app factory). If you use any flask extensions, like flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, etc., this can be in the same place as where they are created.

Answer (score 2):

I found [@Garrett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463669/417629) to be a bit more complex than what I wanted. I found that I can easily inspect the context by adding a clone of the context to the context itself:

```
contextCopy = dict(context)
context['all'] = contextCopy
```

And then pretty printing that into my Jinja template with `<pre>{{ all|pprint }}</pre>`.