# How do I debug python sphinx themes?

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I want to edit a [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) theme and can't understand what variables are present in the document. The official documentation laks any kind of information.

How do I see what variables are present in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this [documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html) page will help you - it describes what blocks, configuration variables, helper functions and global variables are available in the template.

And, by default `sphinx` uses `jinja2` templating language - so you can print out the whole template context, like it was suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398850/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-variables-from-jinja-2-template) (not sure it'll work in your case).

Hope that helps.