# Print all jinja2 variables in a template

Tags: python, jinja2

How can I print all variables in a jinja2 html template? Is there a list or dict of them I can access and view?  I need to be able to do this with out editing the python backend.

```
{% for var in LIST_OF_VARS %}
  {{ var }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is not a duplicate of this question
[How to get a list of current variables from Jinja 2 template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398850/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-variables-from-jinja-2-template)
because I need to accomplish this without editing the python backend and adding new code.

Comment: @martijn-pieters I updated the question so it is not a duplicate.  Can you unmark it?

Comment: It is still a duplicate. That post outlines your options, that is *it*. There is no way to do this in just the template.

Comment: I'd not say this is duplicate, the question is about rendering vars in template, not python code, this is what I was looking for. This is different question. If there is no way to do this, it have to be stated this clearly.