# Referencing jinja2 variable from a variable

Tags: variables, jinja2

I want to be able to apply DRY and not have to repeat myself when building my jinja2 template. So I would like to be able to reference a variable within the jinja2 template from a dynamically constructed variable name, eg:

```
{% for a in [ 'a', 'b', 'c'] %}
{% set name = a + "_name" %}
{% set value = {{ name }} %}
hello there {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

where my input variables into jinja would be

```
a_name = 1
b_name = 2
c_name = 3
```

and I the result would be

```
hello there 1
hello there 2
hello there 3
```

is this possible?

I know i would just pass in a datastructure into jinja2 to do something similar, but I am not at liberty to modify what goes into the template.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398850/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-variables-from-jinja-2-template)

basically, define a `contextfunction` and reference it within the jinja code:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, contextfunction

j2_env = Environment( loader=FileSystemLoader(directory), trim_blocks=False )
this_template = j2_env.get_template( """
    {% for i in [ 'a', 'b', 'c'] %}
    hello there {{ context()[i+"_name"] }}
    {% endfor %}
""" )

@contextfunction
def get_context(c):
  return c
this_template.globals['context'] = get_context
this_template.render( **{ 'a_name': 1, 'b_name': 2, 'c_name': 3 } )
```