# how to list available arguments in a jinja template

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, templating

I have a template, say with one **variable** `NAME`

```
my_template = "Hello {{ NAME }}"
```

Eventually the code will `render` the template, eg:

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template(my_template)
// what code would return 'NAME' here?
rendered = template.render(NAME="frank")
```

I need to get the list of **variables** / "available args" to the template.  In this case, this would return `NAME` (likely in a collection of some sort).

(My detailed use case is I accept templates that may, optionally, include some well-known *template-variable* names, which I need to pull out, and then add to the *context* as i call `render()`)

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398850/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-variables-from-jinja-2-template), though maybe something has changed in the 8 years passed since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was blocked on this, so eventually found the answer.  This requires `jinja2.meta`

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, meta
env = Environment()
ast = env.parse(code_string)
for var in meta.find_undeclared_variables(ast):
    print(var)   # <-----
template = Template(code_string)
template.render( # ... args
```